# NSScrollView scrollbars always visible on macbook

Tags: macos, nsscrollview

When for some reason I disconnect my mouse on my iMac I noticie that the scroll bars on all NSScrollView instances remain visible. Now that I'm looking at my app on a macbook with "El Capitan" I see that with only a trackpad the same this is happening. The scrollbars remain visible, but it is unnecessary.
What is the reason for this behavior ? Could this behavior be changed vía a property in NSScrollView ?

Comment: Have you checked System Preferences > General > Show scroll bar?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Thank you Zoff, its on "automatically based on mouse or trackpad"

Comment: Abizern, my concern was that this behavior could be manipulated vía a property of NSScrollView.

Comment: You can set `scrollerStyle = .overlay`  on `NSScrollView`